# Where database(openDatabase) file located in android?

Tags: android, html, cordova

> db = openDatabase("mydb", "1.0", "database", 200000);

I'm using phonegap + html5, and when i use db to `create if not exists table...`, where is the database file located in my android device? can't find anywhere... I have my log showing that the table is created.

Comment: I would like to know the answer to this as well. My guess is that since phonegap apps run a webview, it's stored in the browser cache, but I really don't know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a thread over at [community.phonegap.com](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/what_is_default_database_path_in_android_using_phonegap) that shows it to be the normal android location:

> `/data/data/[full_package_name]/app_database/file__0/0000000000000001.db`

**Note**: the actual file name and numbers differ

Comment: there is no folder called /data/data in my tablets and smartphones.

Comment: pretty sure you have to be rooted to even see these directories. If your device isn't rooted, you won't see them, let alone be able to actually do anything with them.